# Hadoop streaming - unexpected argument

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to execute the command below on cloudera hadoop, but it runs into problem and I am getting the error message.
Not sure if its a bug or I have done something wrong.
Any information would be much appreciated.

```
 hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -files /home/cloudera/mapper.py /home/cloudera/reducer.py -mapper "python mapper.py" -reducer "python reducer.py" -input /user/cloudera/test_file -output /user/cloudera/wc_output01
```

error message:

> Found 1 unexpected arguments on the command line [/home/cloudera/reducer.py]
>      Try -help for more information
>      Streaming Command Failed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get insight into the error by [reading the documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html)

> The -files and -archives options are generic options. Be sure to place the generic options before the command options, otherwise the command will fail.

You correctly placed the argument, so that's not the issue

> Multiple entries can be specified like this:
>
> `-files hdfs://host:fs_port/user/testfile1.txt,hdfs://host:fs_port/user/testfile2.txt`

You have no comma between the mapper and reducer files

---

You can just pass `mapper.py` if the file is executable and starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Answer (score 1):

Figured the issue. I used -files which was creating issue. Earlier I had used -file but console gave the warning 'deprecated, use -files as generic option'. But this didnot solve the issue so I reverted back to -file option and it ran giving the same warning.